# How to fix AttributeError when using barplot in python?

Tags: python, list, bar-chart, seaborn, attributeerror

I'm trying to get a barplot out of some data in python through using the library seaborn. My data looks something like this:

```py
data_list = [[value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I'm now trying to execute the following command:

```py
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'x_name', y = 'y_name', data = data_list)
```

Unfortunately, instead of getting a barplot, I get the following line:

```
File "C:\Users\ (my name) \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 146, in establish_variables            
x = data.get(x, x)  
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I fix this error? Do I need to provide the data in a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) specifies that data optional argument needs to be `DataFrame, array, or list of arrays`, whereas yours is a list of lists. But you can also just pass the individual data arrays directly to the positional arguments `x` and `y`:

```
ax = sns.barplot(data_list[0], data_list[1])
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You have given your data as list, but it is expecting a dict

Try changing your code from

```
data_list = [[value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

to

```
data_dict = {'value_1': 1, 'value_2': 2, 'value_3': 3, 'value_4': 4}
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'x_name', y = 'y_name', data = data_dict)
```